# Django - reverting an un applied migration

Tags: django, django-south

I mistakenly run:

```
python manage.py schemamigration auth --initial
```

And immediately got:

```
 + Added model auth.Permission
 + Added unique constraint for ['content_type', 'codename'] on auth.Permission
 + Added model auth.Group
 + Added M2M table for permissions on auth.Group
 + Added model auth.User
 + Added M2M table for groups on auth.User
 + Added M2M table for user_permissions on auth.User
Created 0001_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate auth
```

Since I don't want to migrate `django.contrib.auth` How do I revert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has just created the migrations files but you have not yet applied these migrations by running the command `./manage.py migrate auth` (make sure you have not done this). So it is safe to delete the migrations files manually.

Comment: I can't access them (cleanly) this is somewhere in the LIB, since this is the contrib..

Comment: Yes I know this is contrib. But can't you find the package and go to auth module and delete migrations folder, what's difficult in that?

Comment: Go to django shell and type this `import django.contrib.auth as auth_module` and then `print auth_module.__file__` gives you module path.